# What is an accepted method of keeping old data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I think this may be more of a programming question, but since it directly relates to MySQL, I wanted to ask it here.

Some background:  I am running an application whereby users can take tests using data from two tables:  questions and answers.  Each response from every test is recorded in a test_data table.  Now, over time, I will have questions that were either put in wrong, or are no longer relavant.  How would I go about keeping that data somewhere in the database so that I maintain referential integrity?

I seem to remember using an application in the past that had an "archive" table with a few columns:

id
type (describes what data is archived in this row)
data (serialized PHP array)
etc...

This could be considered a subjective question, yes.  But what I'm looking for here are some possibilities that I can use to build an archiving system with in MySQL.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could duplicate the table structure entirely, but under a different name, ie. `questions_archive`. Then move all of the now-irrelevant data into that table and only refer to it in your query via `UNION` with the original table if it is truly necessary. To maintain referential integrity you'll likely want to create a similar archive table for `answers`.

You should also be able to specify this table's data be stored on a higher-latency, higher-capacity volume [ie: spindle drive vs SSD, NFS share vs local, etc] if you are looking for further optimization for your non-archived data.

edit: Alternatively, [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html).